# php imap - some email body with not understandable data

Tags: php, email, imap, decode

I have email reading using php_imap and most of e-mails are OK, I can read and decode the body, the data is readable and nice. But there are some e-mail with not understandable data. Like:

```
R0lGODlhSwBLAPcAAAAmAQAvDQAyEAA0EwA6GQA/HwBCIwBGKQBIKgBMLgBOMQBPNABQMwBRNABU
OQBVOgBWOgFWPAJYPQRYPQhXPw9XPwlYPgZZQAdcQghaQApcQgxdQw1dRRJbQhFeRRZaQxRcQxZg
RxBhSBZhSRVkSxRlTBlhSRtjTBtlTB1iTB1kTRtoUhxqUSFiSyJlTiBmUCNoUiJsVSVoUSZoUiZr
VihqUylrVihuWC5tWCpwWi5xXC51XzFuWTRvWzhvWzJxXDNyXTFzXjdzXjtwXDxzXy52YDR3YjN4
Yzd5YzV5ZDt1YT13ZDp5ZDp8Zz16Zz19aUN3ZEd4ZEN7aUR8aUp6aE17alN/bll8a0WCb06Ab0qC
...
```

What can I do to retrieve the understandable data of the body? How can I decode it?

Comment: Isn't that the Base64 header for a gif?

Comment: How can I detect, if it's base64? The `mb_detect_encoding gives` only ascii or utf8

Comment: found it :) `base64_decode($row['text'],1)` thanks!

Comment: there is an other problem, `base64_decode($row['text'],1)` doesn't give `false` but decodes the string to another not understandable data: 
`�|��`

Comment: Is the string a gif?

Comment: My information is the e-mails contain texts... js `atob` returns error: `InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character`

Comment: but maybe it's a gif... can't think anything else...

Comment: OK, I got informatiun about the bodys of emails, IBM client, can insert files (word, pdf) to the body... -.-'